# How to get the price of an app in Steam WebAPI?

Tags: steam, steam-web-api

Is there a possibility to get the price of a game from Steam over the WebAPI?

Answer (score 78, accepted):

In current days, we have an API call. This means we could use [`JSON`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.json.php) for it:

Appid 57690 = Tropico 4

- http://store.steampowered.com/api/appdetails?appids=57690

Part of the response:

```json
"price_overview":{
    "currency":"EUR",
    "initial":2999,
    "final":2999,
    "discount_percent":0
}
```

The Price is looking like you should convert 2999 to 29.99

Full response:

```json
{
   "57690":{
      "success":true,
      "data":{
         "type":"game",
         "name":"Tropico 4: Steam Special Edition",
         "steam_appid":"57690",
         "required_age":0,
         "dlc":[
            "205630",
            "205636",
            "205635",
            "205637",
            "205638",
            "205634",
            "205633",
            "205632",
            "57697",
            "57695",
            "57696"
         ],
         "detailed_description":"<h1>Sonderedition<\/h1><p>...inklusive einer exklusiven Insel (Isla Nublar), einem El Presidente Avatar-Kost\u00fcm (Luchador) und 50 Steam-Errungenschaften. El Presidente ist zur\u00fcck um alles zu beherrschen!<\/p><br><h1>\u00dcber das Spiel<\/h1>Die Zeiten \u00e4ndern sich! Gro\u00dfm\u00e4chte kommen und gehen und der Weltmarkt wird von neuen Global Playern beherrscht, mit neuen Anforderungen und Angeboten \u2013 und auch El Presidente muss sich neuen Herausforderungen stellen. Wenn Sie \u00fcber die Neinsager triumphieren wollen, m\u00fcssen Sie so viel Unterst\u00fctzung vom Volk bekommen, wie m\u00f6glich. Ihre Entscheidungen werden die Zukunft Ihrer Nation bestimmen und, noch viel wichtiger ist, die Gr\u00f6\u00dfe Ihres ausl\u00e4ndischen Bankverm\u00f6gens!\r<br>Tropico 4 bietet Ihnen erweiterte politische M\u00f6glichkeiten sowie zus\u00e4tzliche Superm\u00e4chte, mit denen Sie verhandeln k\u00f6nnen. Au\u00dferdem setzen Sie nun Minister ein, um Ihre etwas \u201eumstritteneren\u201c Vorhaben durchzusetzen. Aber denken Sie daran: Halten Sie Ihre Freunde nahe, aber Ihre Feinde noch n\u00e4her! Ihr politischer Eifer wird auf den Pr\u00fcfstand gestellt. Neue Naturkatastrophen sorgen daf\u00fcr, dass sich Ihr Volk nach Hilfe von Ihnen und Ihrem Kabinett gegen den Unmut von Mutter Natur sehnt.\r<br>Mit Facebook- und Twitter-Einbindung (nur auf Windows PC) hebt Tropico 4 auch die Interaktion auf ein neues Level. Verfassen Sie Kommentare f\u00fcr Twitter direkt aus dem Spiel heraus und versenden Sie automatisch Updates, wenn Sie Missionen abschlie\u00dfen oder neue Achievements freischalten. Au\u00dferdem k\u00f6nnen Sie Screenshots Ihres wachsenden Inselstaates machen und die Bilder Ihrer traumhaften Kreation auf Ihrer Tropico 4 Facebook-Seite posten sowie Ihre Diktator-Wertung auf den interaktiven Online-Ranglisten mit der von anderen Spielern vergleichen.<h2 class=\"bb_tag\">Eigenschaften:<\/h2><ul class=\"bb_ul\"><li>Umfangreiche Kampagne mit 20 Missionen und 10 neuen Karten \r<br><\/li><li>20 neue Geb\u00e4ude \u2013 B\u00f6rse, Einkaufszentrum, Wasserpark, Mausoleum etc.\r<br><\/li><li>Neue interaktive Desaster wie Vulkanausbr\u00fcche, D\u00fcrren oder Tornados \r<br><\/li><li>Der Ministerrat \u2013 berufen Sie ausgew\u00e4hlte Einwohner in den Ministerrat, um schwierige Entscheidungen &quot;durchzudr\u00fccken&quot; \r<br><\/li><li>National Agenda \u2013 erhalte Zielvorgaben von anderen Fraktionen oder ausl\u00e4ndischen Regierungen, die sich auf aktuelle Ereignisse beziehen\r<br><\/li><li>Facebook &amp; Twitter Integration \u2013 ver\u00f6ffentlicht Live-Tweeds direkt aus dem Spiel; speichert und zeigt Errungenschaften auf einer Tropico-4-Facebook-Seite an; Vergleiche deinen El Presidente mit dem von anderen Spielern (PC) \r<br><\/li><li>Screenshot Gallerie \u2013 Nehmen Sie Screenshots Ihrer tropischen Paradiesinseln auf und ver\u00f6ffentlichen Sie sie auf Ihrer Facebook Seite.\r<br><\/li><li>Neues Handels-System \u2013 Import und Export von Waren von anderen Nationen<\/li><\/ul>",
         "about_the_game":"Die Zeiten \u00e4ndern sich! Gro\u00dfm\u00e4chte kommen und gehen und der Weltmarkt wird von neuen Global Playern beherrscht, mit neuen Anforderungen und Angeboten \u2013 und auch El Presidente muss sich neuen Herausforderungen stellen. Wenn Sie \u00fcber die Neinsager triumphieren wollen, m\u00fcssen Sie so viel Unterst\u00fctzung vom Volk bekommen, wie m\u00f6glich. Ihre Entscheidungen werden die Zukunft Ihrer Nation bestimmen und, noch viel wichtiger ist, die Gr\u00f6\u00dfe Ihres ausl\u00e4ndischen Bankverm\u00f6gens!\r<br>Tropico 4 bietet Ihnen erweiterte politische M\u00f6glichkeiten sowie zus\u00e4tzliche Superm\u00e4chte, mit denen Sie verhandeln k\u00f6nnen. Au\u00dferdem setzen Sie nun Minister ein, um Ihre etwas \u201eumstritteneren\u201c Vorhaben durchzusetzen. Aber denken Sie daran: Halten Sie Ihre Freunde nahe, aber Ihre Feinde noch n\u00e4her! Ihr politischer Eifer wird auf den Pr\u00fcfstand gestellt. Neue Naturkatastrophen sorgen daf\u00fcr, dass sich Ihr Volk nach Hilfe von Ihnen und Ihrem Kabinett gegen den Unmut von Mutter Natur sehnt.\r<br>Mit Facebook- und Twitter-Einbindung (nur auf Windows PC) hebt Tropico 4 auch die Interaktion auf ein neues Level. Verfassen Sie Kommentare f\u00fcr Twitter direkt aus dem Spiel heraus und versenden Sie automatisch Updates, wenn Sie Missionen abschlie\u00dfen oder neue Achievements freischalten. Au\u00dferdem k\u00f6nnen Sie Screenshots Ihres wachsenden Inselstaates machen und die Bilder Ihrer traumhaften Kreation auf Ihrer Tropico 4 Facebook-Seite posten sowie Ihre Diktator-Wertung auf den interaktiven Online-Ranglisten mit der von anderen Spielern vergleichen.<h2 class=\"bb_tag\">Eigenschaften:<\/h2><ul class=\"bb_ul\"><li>Umfangreiche Kampagne mit 20 Missionen und 10 neuen Karten \r<br><\/li><li>20 neue Geb\u00e4ude \u2013 B\u00f6rse, Einkaufszentrum, Wasserpark, Mausoleum etc.\r<br><\/li><li>Neue interaktive Desaster wie Vulkanausbr\u00fcche, D\u00fcrren oder Tornados \r<br><\/li><li>Der Ministerrat \u2013 berufen Sie ausgew\u00e4hlte Einwohner in den Ministerrat, um schwierige Entscheidungen &quot;durchzudr\u00fccken&quot; \r<br><\/li><li>National Agenda \u2013 erhalte Zielvorgaben von anderen Fraktionen oder ausl\u00e4ndischen Regierungen, die sich auf aktuelle Ereignisse beziehen\r<br><\/li><li>Facebook &amp; Twitter Integration \u2013 ver\u00f6ffentlicht Live-Tweeds direkt aus dem Spiel; speichert und zeigt Errungenschaften auf einer Tropico-4-Facebook-Seite an; Vergleiche deinen El Presidente mit dem von anderen Spielern (PC) \r<br><\/li><li>Screenshot Gallerie \u2013 Nehmen Sie Screenshots Ihrer tropischen Paradiesinseln auf und ver\u00f6ffentlichen Sie sie auf Ihrer Facebook Seite.\r<br><\/li><li>Neues Handels-System \u2013 Import und Export von Waren von anderen Nationen<\/li><\/ul>",
         "supported_languages":"Englisch<strong>*<\/strong>, Franz\u00f6sisch<strong>*<\/strong>, Deutsch<strong>*<\/strong>, Italienisch<strong>*<\/strong>, Spanisch<strong>*<\/strong>, Koreanisch<br><strong>*<\/strong>Sprachen mit voller Audiounterst\u00fctzung",
         "reviews":"\u201cWillkommen im Paradies.\u201d\r<br>\u2013 <a href=\"http:\/\/www.gamesradar.com\/pc\/tropico-4\/preview\/e3-2011-tropico-4-preview-volcanoes-assassinations-and-oil-spills-welcome-to-paradise\/a-20110615155511892017\/g-20110202164557738087\" target=\"_blank\"  >Gamesradar<\/a>\r<br>\u201cDiese Fortsetzung wird auf dem aufbauen, was man in Haemimont's Tropico 3 genossen hat und mehr davon anbieten.\u201d\r<br>\u2013 <a href=\"http:\/\/gdc.gamespot.com\/story\/6302598\/spotlight-on-tropico-4-at-gdc-2011\" target=\"_blank\"  >GameSpot<\/a>",
         "header_image":"http:\/\/cdn4.steampowered.com\/v\/gfx\/apps\/57690\/header.jpg?t=1387657216",
         "website":"http:\/\/www.worldoftropico.com\/",
         "pc_requirements":{
            "minimum":"<ul class=\"bb_ul\"><li><strong>Betriebssystem:<\/strong> Windows XP SP3 (32-bit), Vista \/ 7 (32 oder 64-bit)\r<br><\/li><li><strong>Prozessor:<\/strong> 2 GHz Dual Core CPU\r<br><\/li><li><strong>Speicher:<\/strong> 1 GB RAM\r<br><\/li><li><strong>Grafik:<\/strong> Shadermodel 3.0 (Geforce 6600 oder h\u00f6her, Radeon X1600-Serie), 256 MB, DirectX 9.0c\r<br><\/li><li><strong>DirectX\u00ae:<\/strong> 9.0c\r<br><\/li><li><strong>Festplatte:<\/strong> 5 GB freier Festplattenspeicher\r<br><\/li><li><strong>Sound:<\/strong> DirectX kompatibel\r<\/li><\/ul>",
            "recommended":"<ul class=\"bb_ul\"><li><strong>Betriebssystem:<\/strong> Windows Vista \/ 7 (32 oder 64-bit)\r<br><\/li><li><strong>Prozessor:<\/strong> 2 GHz Quad Core CPU\r<br><\/li><li><strong>Speicher:<\/strong> 2 GB RAM\r<br><\/li><li><strong>Grafik:<\/strong> Shadermodel 3.0 (Geforce 8800 oder h\u00f6her, Radeon HD4000-Serie oder h\u00f6her), 512 MB, DirectX 9.0c\r<br><\/li><li><strong>DirectX\u00ae:<\/strong> 9.0c\r<br><\/li><li><strong>Festplatte:<\/strong> 5 GB freier Festplattenspeicher\r<br><\/li><li><strong>Sound:<\/strong> DirectX kompatibel\r<\/li><\/ul>"
         },
         "mac_requirements":[

         ],
         "linux_requirements":[

         ],
         "drm_notice":"Requires a free Kalypso account",
         "developers":[
            "Haemimont Games"
         ],
         "publishers":[
            "Kalypso Media Digital"
         ],
         "demos":[
            {
               "appid":"57750",
               "description":""
            }
         ],
         "price_overview":{
            "currency":"EUR",
            "initial":2999,
            "final":2999,
            "discount_percent":0
         },
         "packages":[
            "11400",
            "19282",
            "1891",
            "2128"
         ],
         "package_groups":[
            {
               "name":"default",
               "title":"Tropico 4: Steam Special Edition kaufen",
               "description":"",
               "selection_text":"Kaufoption ausw\u00e4hlen",
               "save_text":"",
               "display_type":"0",
               "is_recurring_subscription":"false",
               "subs":[
                  {
                     "packageid":"11400",
                     "percent_savings_text":"",
                     "percent_savings":0,
                     "option_text":"Tropico 4 - 29,99\u20ac ",
                     "option_description":""
                  },
                  {
                     "packageid":"19282",
                     "percent_savings_text":"",
                     "percent_savings":0,
                     "option_text":"Tropico 4 Collector's Bundle - 39,99\u20ac ",
                     "option_description":""
                  },
                  {
                     "packageid":"1891",
                     "percent_savings_text":"",
                     "percent_savings":0,
                     "option_text":"Tropico Reloaded - 6,99\u20ac ",
                     "option_description":""
                  },
                  {
                     "packageid":"2128",
                     "percent_savings_text":"",
                     "percent_savings":0,
                     "option_text":"Tropico 3 - 9,99\u20ac ",
                     "option_description":""
                  }
               ]
            }
         ],
         "platforms":{
            "windows":true,
            "mac":false,
            "linux":false
         },
         "metacritic":{
            "score":78,
            "url":"http:\/\/www.metacritic.com\/game\/pc\/tropico-4"
         },
         "categories":[
            {
               "id":"2",
               "description":"Einzelspieler"
            },
            {
               "id":"29",
               "description":"Steam-Sammelkarten"
            }
         ],
         "genres":[
            {
               "id":"28",
               "description":"Simulation"
            },
            {
               "id":"2",
               "description":"Strategie"
            }
         ],
         "screenshots":[
            {
               "id":0,
               "path_thumbnail":"http:\/\/cdn4.steampowered.com\/v\/gfx\/apps\/57690\/ss_833be037c67d21af2777a0066d278891d0f2adbb.600x338.jpg?t=1387657216",
               "path_full":"http:\/\/cdn4.steampowered.com\/v\/gfx\/apps\/57690\/ss_833be037c67d21af2777a0066d278891d0f2adbb.1920x1080.jpg?t=1387657216"
            },
            {
               "id":1,
               "path_thumbnail":"http:\/\/cdn4.steampowered.com\/v\/gfx\/apps\/57690\/ss_8b9cb3571d92cbe2efbf091a6c192c366dd81a74.600x338.jpg?t=1387657216",
               "path_full":"http:\/\/cdn4.steampowered.com\/v\/gfx\/apps\/57690\/ss_8b9cb3571d92cbe2efbf091a6c192c366dd81a74.1920x1080.jpg?t=1387657216"
            },
            {
               "id":2,
               "path_thumbnail":"http:\/\/cdn4.steampowered.com\/v\/gfx\/apps\/57690\/ss_8b95fda44ffdbb4fb76b1629fdd1d0cc4bf288dd.600x338.jpg?t=1387657216",
               "path_full":"http:\/\/cdn4.steampowered.com\/v\/gfx\/apps\/57690\/ss_8b95fda44ffdbb4fb76b1629fdd1d0cc4bf288dd.1920x1080.jpg?t=1387657216"
            },
            {
               "id":3,
               "path_thumbnail":"http:\/\/cdn4.steampowered.com\/v\/gfx\/apps\/57690\/ss_850d6465eef278d3a4dc44121b25d338720ff35d.600x338.jpg?t=1387657216",
               "path_full":"http:\/\/cdn4.steampowered.com\/v\/gfx\/apps\/57690\/ss_850d6465eef278d3a4dc44121b25d338720ff35d.1920x1080.jpg?t=1387657216"
            },
            {
               "id":4,
               "path_thumbnail":"http:\/\/cdn4.steampowered.com\/v\/gfx\/apps\/57690\/ss_c65dcb77d525880ed5c99b58a07d8c27d44f8c0d.600x338.jpg?t=1387657216",
               "path_full":"http:\/\/cdn4.steampowered.com\/v\/gfx\/apps\/57690\/ss_c65dcb77d525880ed5c99b58a07d8c27d44f8c0d.1920x1080.jpg?t=1387657216"
            },
            {
               "id":5,
               "path_thumbnail":"http:\/\/cdn4.steampowered.com\/v\/gfx\/apps\/57690\/ss_3f5971572fdd8f31f738121df95d51fcb2cfa14f.600x338.jpg?t=1387657216",
               "path_full":"http:\/\/cdn4.steampowered.com\/v\/gfx\/apps\/57690\/ss_3f5971572fdd8f31f738121df95d51fcb2cfa14f.1920x1080.jpg?t=1387657216"
            },
            {
               "id":6,
               "path_thumbnail":"http:\/\/cdn4.steampowered.com\/v\/gfx\/apps\/57690\/ss_171d661336b3761a3f1ace44af0e198ce16ffdd0.600x338.jpg?t=1387657216",
               "path_full":"http:\/\/cdn4.steampowered.com\/v\/gfx\/apps\/57690\/ss_171d661336b3761a3f1ace44af0e198ce16ffdd0.1920x1080.jpg?t=1387657216"
            },
            {
               "id":7,
               "path_thumbnail":"http:\/\/cdn4.steampowered.com\/v\/gfx\/apps\/57690\/ss_705c724eae6f1abc743d1ae6deff66722cd57f50.600x338.jpg?t=1387657216",
               "path_full":"http:\/\/cdn4.steampowered.com\/v\/gfx\/apps\/57690\/ss_705c724eae6f1abc743d1ae6deff66722cd57f50.1920x1080.jpg?t=1387657216"
            },
            {
               "id":8,
               "path_thumbnail":"http:\/\/cdn4.steampowered.com\/v\/gfx\/apps\/57690\/ss_e8d28c65adc8c7659377db890d98748dc835d3fa.600x338.jpg?t=1387657216",
               "path_full":"http:\/\/cdn4.steampowered.com\/v\/gfx\/apps\/57690\/ss_e8d28c65adc8c7659377db890d98748dc835d3fa.1920x1080.jpg?t=1387657216"
            },
            {
               "id":9,
               "path_thumbnail":"http:\/\/cdn4.steampowered.com\/v\/gfx\/apps\/57690\/ss_3017c40b6c0dff7fcb1abea515627e4a2c813ad9.600x338.jpg?t=1387657216",
               "path_full":"http:\/\/cdn4.steampowered.com\/v\/gfx\/apps\/57690\/ss_3017c40b6c0dff7fcb1abea515627e4a2c813ad9.1920x1080.jpg?t=1387657216"
            },
            {
               "id":10,
               "path_thumbnail":"http:\/\/cdn4.steampowered.com\/v\/gfx\/apps\/57690\/ss_f435b4376629784b5d4cd8657f7eb2a9883d554c.600x338.jpg?t=1387657216",
               "path_full":"http:\/\/cdn4.steampowered.com\/v\/gfx\/apps\/57690\/ss_f435b4376629784b5d4cd8657f7eb2a9883d554c.1920x1080.jpg?t=1387657216"
            },
            {
               "id":11,
               "path_thumbnail":"http:\/\/cdn4.steampowered.com\/v\/gfx\/apps\/57690\/ss_eeb9d00e103d98a1edee392e633d88a88f2d10c2.600x338.jpg?t=1387657216",
               "path_full":"http:\/\/cdn4.steampowered.com\/v\/gfx\/apps\/57690\/ss_eeb9d00e103d98a1edee392e633d88a88f2d10c2.1920x1080.jpg?t=1387657216"
            },
            {
               "id":12,
               "path_thumbnail":"http:\/\/cdn4.steampowered.com\/v\/gfx\/apps\/57690\/ss_7214b3771fd452007a4c7a36b46abba453c8b835.600x338.jpg?t=1387657216",
               "path_full":"http:\/\/cdn4.steampowered.com\/v\/gfx\/apps\/57690\/ss_7214b3771fd452007a4c7a36b46abba453c8b835.1920x1080.jpg?t=1387657216"
            },
            {
               "id":13,
               "path_thumbnail":"http:\/\/cdn4.steampowered.com\/v\/gfx\/apps\/57690\/ss_99e847d54bafb0b7c56402851ce55493dc7de593.600x338.jpg?t=1387657216",
               "path_full":"http:\/\/cdn4.steampowered.com\/v\/gfx\/apps\/57690\/ss_99e847d54bafb0b7c56402851ce55493dc7de593.1920x1080.jpg?t=1387657216"
            },
            {
               "id":14,
               "path_thumbnail":"http:\/\/cdn4.steampowered.com\/v\/gfx\/apps\/57690\/ss_480451bdd44a1d900dd200d467164d753bde2163.600x338.jpg?t=1387657216",
               "path_full":"http:\/\/cdn4.steampowered.com\/v\/gfx\/apps\/57690\/ss_480451bdd44a1d900dd200d467164d753bde2163.1920x1080.jpg?t=1387657216"
            },
            {
               "id":15,
               "path_thumbnail":"http:\/\/cdn4.steampowered.com\/v\/gfx\/apps\/57690\/ss_01eeca8397b145c18f170ccb47d7a8cc228daad1.600x338.jpg?t=1387657216",
               "path_full":"http:\/\/cdn4.steampowered.com\/v\/gfx\/apps\/57690\/ss_01eeca8397b145c18f170ccb47d7a8cc228daad1.1920x1080.jpg?t=1387657216"
            }
         ],
         "movies":[
            {
               "id":"80906",
               "name":"Tropico 4 Coming Soon Trailer",
               "thumbnail":"http:\/\/cdn4.steampowered.com\/v\/gfx\/apps\/80906\/movie.293x165.jpg?t=1379336376",
               "webm":{
                  "480":"http:\/\/media3.steampowered.com\/steam\/apps\/80906\/movie480.webm?t=1379336376",
                  "max":"http:\/\/media3.steampowered.com\/steam\/apps\/80906\/movie_max.webm?t=1379336376"
               },
               "highlight":true
            },
            {
               "id":"2029441",
               "name":"Tropico 4 Gameplay Trailer",
               "thumbnail":"http:\/\/cdn4.steampowered.com\/v\/gfx\/apps\/2029441\/movie.jpg?t=1379337116",
               "webm":{
                  "480":"http:\/\/media3.steampowered.com\/steam\/apps\/2029441\/movie480.webm?t=1379337116",
                  "max":"http:\/\/media3.steampowered.com\/steam\/apps\/2029441\/movie_max.webm?t=1379337116"
               },
               "highlight":true
            }
         ],
         "recommendations":{
            "total":7374
         },
         "achievements":{
            "total":0
         },
         "release_date":{
            "coming_soon":false,
            "date":"1 Sep. 2011"
         },
         "support_info":{
            "url":"",
            "email":"support@kalypsomedia.com"
         }
      }
   }
}
```

But disclaimer: This is not an official public API. This is an implementation for Steam's Big Picture Mode, and can change anytime.

You can get all apps (games), and the IDs for it, by using this API:

- http://api.steampowered.com/ISteamApps/GetAppList/v0001/

You will get nearly every information you need about a game (including screenshots).

**Currency Code and Language**

You can change currency code by adding the parameter `cc`. The language can be changed using the parameter `l`.

For example:

- http://store.steampowered.com/api/appdetails?appids=57690&cc=us&l=en
- http://store.steampowered.com/api/appdetails?appids=57690&cc=gb&l=en
- http://store.steampowered.com/api/appdetails?appids=57690&cc=de&l=de

Important:

If it doesn't seems to change anything, you are most probably logged into steam with your user account in the current browser. Use another one .

**Documentation**

Here is an unoffical link, which describes the current known Store API (Which is still not public and can change anytime!):

- https://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/User:RJackson/StorefrontAPI#Known_methods

Comment: Oh, this is very nice. Note that multiple appIDs seem to be supported, e.g. http://store.steampowered.com/api/appdetails/?appids=440,9050

Comment: Not any more it seems - any attempt to pass multiple appids throws a 400 error...

Comment: Steam is limiting this API. It used to support multiple IDs, but no more, and it used to support several fetches within a few seconds, but now it seems to limit you to about 100 fetches every few minutes or so, something like that.

Comment: Any alternate methods of getting the information, then, prefereable with multiple ID support?

Comment: @PhillipGooch you can see all availible Endpoints here: http://api.steampowered.com/ISteamWebAPIUtil/GetSupportedAPIList/v0001/ Until there is nothing listed related to the store, I can not imagine, there is a better way.

Comment: Does someone by chance have a documentation for the store API? `/appdetails` is great, but maybe there's more possible requests I can do that can also help me out. I can't seem to find a list of available requests anywhere online.

Comment: @Padarom Take a look here: https://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/User:RJackson/StorefrontAPI#Known_methods

Comment: @ChristianGollhardt Hi, I am in England. When i go to any of the 3 links in your post with &cc=us, &cc=gb, &cc=de the 'price_overview.currency' section always shows as GPB

Comment: Damn it :D Are you by chance logged in with your User Account? I used another browser, and it was working for me @472084