# Steam Store API

Tags: node.js, api, steam, steam-web-api

I'd love to know if there is a steam API or something, that gets all current steam games and their price? I need to make a Steam Key Trading Bot that sells Steam Game Keys so I need prices of games and actual games to update automatically.

So what I'm asking is if anyone knows where I can get my hands on an automatic updating Steam Games and Pricelist.

I know this exists:
http://api.steampowered.com/ISteamApps/GetAppList/v0001

But it dosen't include price..

Comment: I have answered exact your question a time ago here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13784059/steam-webapi-get-the-price-of-an-app/22290599#22290599

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can get detailed information about apps by making a request to

```
http://store.steampowered.com/api/appdetails?appids=<appid>
```

The JSON response contains a field called `price_overview` which holds the price- and discount-information.
However, you have to make this request for each app you want to check.

EDIT:
According to [this post](https://steamdb.info/forum/296/steam-api-game-informations/), the support for multiple appids has been removed and the api is limited to 200 requests per 5 minutes.